# Apache airflow default email sender using O365 without SMTP AUTH

Tags: airflow, office365

How do I configure the email settings in Apache Airflow so that emails are sent with an Office 365 account which cannot use the SMTP AUTH protocol?

Is there an OAuth2 authentication method or some other non-legacy version? Microsoft has started to [deprecate basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online?source=recommendations).